# Java Replace unicode chars in string

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a program that reads in a file. In this file there are some crazy chars that I have never seen before. The purpose of this file is to parse certain information into SQL statements.

When I get to this line in the file "read “Details for …(the name of the title”" (notice the horizontal ellipses and the right/left quotes), it outputs into this:

�Details for �(the name of the title�

I just want to replace the chars that are right with chars defined by me. I have tried:

```
st = st.replaceAll("…","...");
st = st.replaceAll("\u2026","...");
```

This is how i read the file:

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file); 
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

And other things that I cant even remember. How can I do this seemingly simple task?

Comment: Can you be more specific, which file you are trying to read? (txt, xls, html etc)

Comment: So you're reading the file in the wrong encoding and want to replace arbitrary chars? Well I can't see what could go wrong with that ;)

Comment: Original file was in rft, it was then saved to txt using Word. I am trying to parse the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's absolutely necessary you don't really have to drop those weird (yet still meaningful) characters...

Have a look at the documentation for [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and specify the right encoding when reading your file.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to call that inputStream? currently I have: FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: You'll find a clear illustrated example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html You will need to find out what specific encoding your .txt file is in (and pass that to the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

You need specify the encoding on read the file before replaces specials chars...

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
// Specify the enconding
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
```